# Commutative ring category is not additive category

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, abelian-categories, additive-categories

I was told that commutative ring category is not additive category all the time and it is thus not abelian category.

A category is additive if $Hom(A,B)$ is abelian group for all objects $A,B$ and morphisms satisfy distributive laws, it has zero objects and it has finite coproduct and products.

It seems commutative ring satisfies most of the requirement except $Hom(A,B)$ being abelian group.

$Hom(A,B)$ is not abelian group by taking any $f\in Hom(A,B)$. If $f$ has inverse $g$, I can check $g(a_1a_2)=f(a_1a_2)$ which never cancels out with $f(a_1a_2)$.

It definitely satisfies distributive laws of morphisms.(Wrong. Distributive law fails due to not fixing $1$.)

Zero object is 0 ring as identity element is $0$ in 0 ring.

Coproduct is tensor and product is direct sum.

Does commutative ring category fail only $Hom(A,B)$ being abelian group requirement?

Comment: What do you mean by "the morphisms satisfy distributive laws" I would interpret that as saying that for appropriate morphisms $f$, $g$, $g'$, $f(g+g')=fg+fg'$ and the symmetrical identity for a different set of appropriate morphisms. However, this assumes already that the hom sets are abelian groups. Hence my confusion, I don't see how morphisms can be distributive in a category which doesn't have hom sets that are abelian groups.

Comment: You can't add two morphisms because you want $f(1) = 1$ which is not an additive condition.

Comment: Also the sentence that begins "$\operatorname{Hom}(A,B)$ is abelian group$\ldots$" confuses me. As in I do not understand at all what is meant.

Comment: @jgon I am not aware that distributive law implies $Hom$ sets are abelian group. I only thought $Hom$ is not abelian group as there may be no inverse elements. Sorry my bad. $Hom(A,B)$ is not abelian group for $A,B$ commutative rings.

Comment: @jgon Yes. I think distributive law of morphisms does not work here for sure as $1$ needs to be fixed. Why distributive law alone would give rise to abelian group structure?

Comment: @user45765 Fair enough, I suppose the minimal structure on the hom sets to meaningfully define "distributive laws" in the sense that most people think of distributive laws would be a commutative monoid.

Comment: @user45765 Note additionally that even if you worked in the category of rings without identity, the fact that homomorphisms preserve multiplication still prevents one from adding them. Suppose for example that $\phi$, $\psi$ are from $R$ to $S$ for rings w/o identity $R$ and $S$. Then $(\phi+\psi)(xy)=\phi(xy)+\psi(xy) =\phi(x)\phi(y) + \psi(x)\psi(y)$, and in general, this is not equal to $(\phi+\psi)(x)(\phi+\psi)(y)=\phi(x)\phi(y)+\phi(x)\psi(y)+\psi(x)\phi(y)+\psi(x)\psi(y)$.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The ring $0$ is not the zero object. Indeed a zero object is an object which is both terminal and initial but in rings with unit the initial object is $\mathbb{Z}$ and the terminal one is $0$.
Moreover, products and coproducts do not coincide. This category will never be an additive category.